# trigger animation on each click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to flip a card using CSS animation. Right now it works but only on the first click of the button. Essentially, my use case is: click button, flip card. click button, flip card etc.

```
function nextCard(){
    document.getElementById('card').addEventListener("click",flipTheCard());
}

function flipTheCard(){
    document.getElementById('card').classList.add('newCard');
}
```

The animation works by adding a class to the card.

```
.newCard {
  animation: flip 1.5s;
  transform-origin: 50% 100% 0;
}
```

I have tried removing the class after the animation and re adding it on each click but this just stops it form working at all.

Any ideas or better ways of doing this? Not sure if adding and removing class to animate is best practice.

Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementById('card').addEventListener("click",flipTheCard());` in this the `flipTheCard` should not be called. Only the reference should be passed. Is this a typo perhaps?

Comment: Could you add the animation too? I highly suggest that you toggle use a `transition` instead, and then toggle the class instead of adding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace this with your code and it will work fine(the way you expect it to work)

```
const card = document.getElementById('card')
function nextCard(){
 card.addEventListener("click",flipTheCard);
}

function flipTheCard(){ 
  card.classList.add('newCard');
  setTimeout(()=> {
    card.classList.remove('newCard')
  },1500)
}
```

Below is the small example which reflects to your question

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

const box = document.querySelector('.box')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  box.classList.add('animate')
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    box.classList.remove('animate')
  },1500)
})
```

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 60vh);
}

.box.animate{
    animation: spin 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes spin{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class='box'></div>
  
  <button class="btn">click</button>
```

Also to answer "if adding and removing class to animate is best practice" there is no harm in doing so.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was after. The setTimeOut was what I was missing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Use classList.toggle instead of classList.add in the function flipTheCard**

`function flipTheCard(){ document.getElementById('card').classList.toggle('newCard'); }`

Comment: This is good but it seems to work only every second click.